# Android can't fetch data from php

Tags: php, android

I am using this adt code to fetch echo data from php url.

```
  class asynctask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseString = null;

        try {

            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                responseString = out.toString();
                out.close();
            } else{
                //Closes the connection.


                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..

        } catch (IOException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..

        }
        return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////    
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {

   //       txv1.setText(result);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception


        }
    }
}
```

And Call from -

```
  new asynctask().execute("http://mmbics.com/get.php");
```

It is really not working even I see what is echoing on php url. It can show other php echo without mysql request. Please kindly help me. 
It can't show this php echo too.

```
  http://mmbics.com/index.php
```

Comment: I have previous experience on getting json data from php url in android, you can use PHP to assign object as json. Then you can use getJsonFromUrl api in java..

Comment: I am sorry, you are posting a great comment to solve the problem. But now I solved it, it is php mysql problem and I separate echo php and config php . It is working well now. Thank you so much for answering.

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest that the DefaultHttpClient is deprecated. You should change it to the OkHttp Client or HttpUrlConnect. See below code snippet that you can take as a reference for make this get request.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("http://mmbics.com/get.php")
  .get()
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Let me know if you stuck with it.It's simple Http Get Request call.

Thanks.

Comment: ``OkHttpClient`` is an external library?

Comment: I am sorry, you are posting a great answer to solve the problem. But now I solved it, it is php/mysql problem and I separate echo php and config php . It is working well now. Thank you so much for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Use Volley its network connectoin lib, its easy and powerfull lib so its better to call your url by this,

```
StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.GET,
                Const.URL_STRING_REQ, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        msgResponse.setText(response.toString());
                        hideProgressDialog();

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        hideProgressDialog();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            public Priority getPriority() {
                return priority;
            }

        };
```

check this reference: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: I am sorry, you are posting a great answer to solve the problem. But now I solved it, it is php mysql problem and I separate echo php and config php . It is working well now. Thank you so much for answering.